# Merging audio files into a video which shows the original file name while playing them

Tags: audio, video-editing, presentation

I have a list of short audio mp3 files. Is there any software which can automatically merge them into a video which show the name of the original audio files while playing them?

For example suppose I have three audio files `human.mp3`, `animal.mp3` and `plant.mp3`. I want to create a video which plays the all the three audios and while playing `human.mp3` it shows the text `human`, while playing while playing `animal.mp3` it shows the text `animal` and while playing `plant.mp3` it shows the text `plant`. So the video show nothing other than text and play the audios.

I'm using Ubuntu and I'm going to use such software in Ubuntu.

Comment: Free or paid? Which OS? Which format should the end video be in?

Comment: Well I prefer a free one. And I prefer a linux-based one.

Comment: format of the video is unimportant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) (Free, open source, cross-platform, CLI) to [create an image from some text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826569/395857):

```
convert \
    -size 165x70 \
    xc:lightblue \
    -font Bookman-DemiItalic \
    -pointsize 12 \
    -fill blue \
    -gravity center \
    -draw "text 0,0 'It is 28 degrees today'" \
    image.png
```

Then you can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) (free and open-source, [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)/Linux/[Mac](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html), CLI) to  [take one image and an audio file as input and generate a video file of the same duration as the audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5887311/395857), e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage \
-c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

Lastly you can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to [concatenate the resulting video files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files).

Comment: The problem is that there are a lot of short mp3 files. And I may need to do this many times for various sets of audio files. I hope there is an automatic way of creating the images using the file names and deriving the movie from them.

Comment: All the above-mentioned tools are CLI, so you can always script around (which I know is not the best solution but in this case I'd be surprised if there exist some pre-packaged solution).

Comment: Can it be done with shell-script for loop for files in a folder?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus yes.

Comment: my ffmpeg has a problem with the option `-tune`

Comment: Sorry I don't know ffmpeg very well, you can try asking on superuser.com!

Answer (score 2):

To complete Franck Dernoncourt's answer: Create a bash script named `0moviemakingscript.sh` in the folder which contains the audio files with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *; do
    if [ "$f" != "0moviemakingscript.sh" ]
    then
        mv "$f" "${f%.*}";
        convert -size 450x280 xc:lightblue -font Bookman-DemiItalic -pointsize 40 -fill blue -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 '$f'" "$f.png";
        ffmpeg -i "$f.png" -i "$f" "$f.avi";
    fi
done

for f in *.avi; do
    echo "file '$f' ";
done > 0.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -i 0.txt -c copy 0merged.avi
```

Open terminal and cd to the folder and then run the script:

```
sh 0moviemakingscript.sh
```

and wait unftil the final video named `0merged.avi` is created.

This script removes the extension from original audio files and it is assumed that the folder does not contain anything other than the audio files and `0moviemakingscript.sh`. So you may need to copy the folder to a temporary folder to created the video. Also note that you can use `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg`. Since `avconv` seems to be derived from `ffmpeg`, I think arguments need not change.